# Access Form Buttons Disappear Between Office Versions

Tags: microsoft-office

I am working with an Enterprise level Access database.  This database contains some basic data entry fields and buttons such as "Find," "Submit," "Clear," etc.  We are, at the same time, updating our user's Microsoft Office Suites to the 2007 version.  What we are now finding is that these form buttons are disappearing from the Access forms when using Access 2007.  The strange this is that the buttons are still there function-wise and will appear *after* you click them.

Has anyone encountered this or have any ideas on how to fix it?

**Edit**

The file the user is working on is an .ade.  As far as I can tell the original database/forms were created in Access 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problems with the display had to do with some outdated custom plugins that were designed for the Access implementation.